# Calculating distance from x and y coordinates from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, distance, filestream

I'm learning Python 3 and I have a question.

I have a text file 'test.txt' and it's contents are:

```
1, 2

3, 4

5, 7

@@@@@@@ 

10, 11

19, 20
```

The number on the left side is an `x` coordinate and the one on the right side is a `y` coordinate. 
I want to get the distance from six digits, and the distance from four digit numbers below '@@@@@@@'.
Since the distance formula is, 
*Distance = SQRT((y2-y1)^2 + (x2-x1)^2)*.

My problem is that I want to extract six numbers, and calculate the total distance from three pairs. For example, 
*total_distance = SQRT((4-2)^2 + (3-1)^2) + SQRT((7-4)^2 + (5-3)^2)*.

After that, I want to get (10, 11) and (19, 20). What makes me confused is that how can I skip '@@@@@@@' and extracting numbers as x and y coordinates.

I began to write code like this:

```
with open("text.txt") as filestream:
    for line in filestream:
        currentline = line.split(",")
```

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue. Can you help me out or give some advise on what should I do?

Comment: You text file displays '@@@@@@@' but you're mentioning  '---------------' in the question, is this expected?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should @@@@@@@

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex:

```
import re

with open("text.txt") as f:
    arr = [[int(l.split(',')[0]), int(l.split(',')[1])] for l in f.readlines() if re.match('\d+, \d+', l)]
```

And if you need the parts separated:

```
import re

arr = []
with open("text.txt") as f:
    parts = re.compile('@+').split(f.read())
    for part in parts:
        arr.append([[int(l.split(',')[0]), int(l.split(',')[1])] for l in part.split('\n') if re.match('\d+, \d+', l)])
```

And all of that is off course, if you are certain that the file exists and has that particular format.

PS: I cant figure out what you are trying to do with those numbers